# How to replace an alternator on a BMW 3 series E46 320d (M47 engine)

Tags: electrical, bmw, alternator

I am trying to replace the alternator on a BMW 320d E46 with an M47 (diesel) engine. I know how to replace an alternator in general (I've done it before on another car where the alternator was a bit easier to reach), but I'm looking for specific instructions for my car, where the alternator is buried pretty deep and it's not immediately obvious how to get it out.

I've been looking on the internet for information, but all the information that I found is about the gasoline version (M57 engine) of my car. The workshop manuals (Haynes, Bentley) are all about the M57 engine as well. The layout is quite different so these instructions are mostly useless for what I want to do.

Any advice on how to replace the alternator or even on how to get the radiator fan out (this is different as well from the M57) would be greatly appreciated.

I think I'll be able to do it eventually regardless, since I know how to replace an alternator, but it would be nice to have some instructions on how to make this as easy and clean as possible. Getting that massive fan out of the way would probably be a good start, so even instructions on how to do just this (in the diesel version!) would be very useful.